# Is there any alternative to python ast module in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

Does Crystal expose its internal parser as a standard library as python does with it's [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module? How to parse crystal source code and get the AST of it?

Comment: See also https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/feature-request-macro-to-pass-code-to-command/1698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! In fact it ships the entire compiler in the stdlib. So we can just access the parser to get an AST:

```
require "compiler/crystal/syntax/*"

root = Crystal::Parser.new(%(
class Foo
  def hello
    :world
  end
end)).parse
```

The official docs do not include the `Crystal::ASTNode` and its subclasses, the ones you find the docs are the ones exposed the macro language and thus slightly differ. So you'll have to dive into the source code to see how to make use of the AST.